# Android error: Failed to resolve: :unspecified: Affected Modules: app

Tags: android, android-studio

I keep getting the error "Failed to resolve: :unspecified: Affected Modules: app" whenever I sync my gradle. This error is not descriptive and hence hard to figure out what's the exact cause for this.

App build.gradle:

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
   compileSdkVersion 29
   buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.sample.sample"
       minSdkVersion 19
       targetSdkVersion 29
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       multiDexEnabled true
       vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
       testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }

   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
}

dependencies {

   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
   //testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

   implementation 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-xiaomi-sdk:1.0.1'
}
```

Project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am using Android Studio 4.1.3 on MacBook Air with macOS 10.15.7

Comment: I have a hunch, can you please once try to build without `com.clevertap.android:clevertap-xiaomi-sdk:1.0.1` dependency and let me know if that works

Comment: yes it works without that dependency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because of `'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-xiaomi-sdk:1.0.1'` This library is not having the correct dependency specified in their pom file.
you can check the same in the link below and scroll down to dependency tag you will see the problem.
[image]

https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.clevertap.android/clevertap-xiaomi-sdk/1.0.1/aar

You can create an issue with clevertap team on this repo
https://github.com/CleverTap/clevertap-android-sdk
for module `clevertap-xps`

Hope I was any help to you.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you! I shall check with the CleverTap team regarding this. The build is successful without the said SDK or for a lower version of this SDK.